# debootstrap does not resolve dependencies

Tags: apt, dpkg, debootstrap, arm64

Debootstrap for foreign arm64 architecture command is unable to resolve dependencies which normally exists on amd64.
I run the following command:

```
debootstrap --arch arm64 --foreign --include=libasound2,libaudit1,libbsd0,libc6,libcairo2,libdatrie1,libdrm2,libegl1,libevdev2,libexpat1,libffi6,libfontconfig1,libgbm1,libgcc1,libgles2,libglib2.0-0,libglvnd0,libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0,libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0,libgstreamer1.0-0,libharfbuzz0b,libinput10,libjpeg-turbo8,libpam0g,libpango-1.0-0,libpangocairo-1.0-0,libpangoft2-1.0-0,libpcre3,libpixman-1-0,libpng16-16,libstdc++6,libudev1,libunwind8,libwayland-client0,libwayland-cursor0,libwayland-egl1,libwayland-server0,libx11-6,libxau6,libxcb1,libxdmcp6,libxext6,libxkbcommon0,libxrender1,python3,zlib1g,kmod,htop --keyring=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg focal build/rootfs
```

The error I get is `E: Couldn't find these debs: libgcc1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libffi6`

When I run `apt-get install --simulate libgcc1:arm64` the package is really not found. `amd64` version exists.

These packages are required by NVIDIA LT4 Support packages.
Does anybody know how can I properly provide debootstrap with all included dependencies?

I build the foreign filesystem on ubuntu 20.04 amd64. Foreign system is ubuntu 20.04 arm64.

```
docker run -it ubuntu:20.04 cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep '^deb '
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse
```

The package exists for `arm64` but cannot by found via `apt install`.
https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libgcc1

Comment: A *amd64* package differs to a *arm64* package. Where all architectures can use a package it'll list as *noarch* or *all* (depending on where/how you look). You haven't provided OS/release details though  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libgcc1)

Comment: @guiverc I build the foreign filesystem on ubuntu 20.04 amd64. The foreign system is ubuntu 20.04 arm64. I updated the question with the details.

Comment: @Richardds You must have been installing amd64 package on arm64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default base image of ubuntu have only the following repository setup:

```
sudo chroot "${ROOTFS}" qemu-aarch64-static /bin/bash -c "cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep '^deb '"
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main
```

By adding the universe repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list` the package is available.

```
sudo chroot "${ROOTFS_DIR}" qemu-aarch64-static /bin/bash -c "echo 'deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal universe' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"

sudo chroot "${ROOTFS_DIR}" qemu-aarch64-static /bin/bash -c "apt update"

sudo chroot "${ROOTFS_DIR}" qemu-aarch64-static /bin/bash -c "apt install --simulate libgcc1"
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgcc1
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst libgcc1 (1:10-20200411-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [arm64])
Conf libgcc1 (1:10-20200411-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu:20.04/focal [arm64])
```